# Chrome download dangerous warning and windows smartscreen

Tags: windows, google-chrome, download, smartscreen

I have made free software and converted it into an NSIS installer. But the issue is that when users download the setup.exe first they get chrome warning `not commonly downloaded and it is dangerous file` with a keep button hidden under an arrow button.
Even if they choose to keep the file, when opening the installer, the windows SmartScreen shows up warning the users again.

Is there a way can I get past these two for free? I mean I don't charge my users anything.

Answer (score 0):

I only know a way to bypass the download warning. However it is not the prettiest solution, but I am currently using this while researching other possibilities.

My way to bypass the SmartScreen download filter is to bundle your setup.exe into a .zip for instance and then download the zip file instead and then the users can run the setup.exe from within. After some testing and feedback, most of our users don't notice this small extra step.

When they run the setup, you need to have signed the installer using a valid certificate for the Windows warning to go away. Here I have not found any clever ways to avoid this. So you need to pay some certificate authority to create a valid certificate for your software.

Hope this answers your question.